# Apache Ignite Kafka connection issues

Tags: apache-kafka, ignite

I'm trying to do stream processing and CEP on a Kafka message stream. For this I picked Apache Ignite to realise a prototype first. However I cannot connect to the queue:

Use 
kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0
apache-ignite-fabric-1.8.0-bin

bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test

Kafka works properly, I tested it with a consumer.
  Then I start ignite, then I run following in a spring boot commandline app.

```
    KafkaStreamer<String, String, String> kafkaStreamer = new KafkaStreamer<>();

    Ignition.setClientMode(true);

    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start();

    Properties settings = new Properties();
    // Set a few key parameters
    settings.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    settings.put("group.id", "test");
    settings.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
    settings.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    settings.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    settings.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    settings.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

    // Create an instance of StreamsConfig from the Properties instance
    kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig config = new ConsumerConfig(settings);

    IgniteCache<String, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache");

    try (IgniteDataStreamer<String, String> stmr = ignite.dataStreamer("myCache")) {
        // allow overwriting cache data
        stmr.allowOverwrite(true);

        kafkaStreamer.setIgnite(ignite);
        kafkaStreamer.setStreamer(stmr);

        // set the topic
        kafkaStreamer.setTopic("test");

        // set the number of threads to process Kafka streams
        kafkaStreamer.setThreads(1);

        // set Kafka consumer configurations
        kafkaStreamer.setConsumerConfig(config);

        // set decoders
        StringDecoder keyDecoder = new StringDecoder(null);
        StringDecoder valueDecoder = new StringDecoder(null);

        kafkaStreamer.setKeyDecoder(keyDecoder);
        kafkaStreamer.setValueDecoder(valueDecoder);

        kafkaStreamer.start();
    } finally {
        kafkaStreamer.stop();
    }
```

When the application starts I get

2017-02-23 10:25:23.409  WARN 1388 --- [           main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties         : Property bootstrap.servers is not valid
2017-02-23 10:25:23.410  INFO 1388 --- [           main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties         : Property group.id is overridden to test
2017-02-23 10:25:23.410  WARN 1388 --- [           main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties         : Property key.deserializer is not valid
2017-02-23 10:25:23.411  WARN 1388 --- [           main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties         : Property key.serializer is not valid
2017-02-23 10:25:23.411  WARN 1388 --- [           main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties         : Property value.deserializer is not valid
2017-02-23 10:25:23.411  WARN 1388 --- [           main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties         : Property value.serializer is not valid
2017-02-23 10:25:23.411  INFO 1388 --- [           main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties         : Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to localhost:2181

Then

2017-02-23 10:25:24.057  WARN 1388 --- [r-finder-thread] kafka.client.ClientUtils$                : Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(test)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(0,user.local,9092)] failed

java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:80) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124) ~[kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59) [kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:94) [kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66) [kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63) [kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar:na]

And reading from the queue doesn't work.
  Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Edit: If I comment the contents of the finally block then following error comes

[2m2017-02-27 16:42:27.780[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m29946[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[pool-3-thread-1][0;39m [36m                                        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Message is ignored due to an error [msg=MessageAndMetadata(test,0,Message(magic = 1, attributes = 0, CreateTime = -1, crc = 2558126716, key = java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1 cap=79], payload = java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=74 cap=74]),15941704,kafka.serializer.StringDecoder@74a96647,kafka.serializer.StringDecoder@42849d34,-1,CreateTime)]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data streamer has been closed.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.enterBusy(DataStreamerImpl.java:401) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addDataInternal(DataStreamerImpl.java:613) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addData(DataStreamerImpl.java:667) ~[ignite-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.KafkaStreamer$1.run(KafkaStreamer.java:180) ~[ignite-kafka-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happens because `KafkaStreamer` is getting closed right after it's started (`kafkaStreamer.stop()` call in `finally` block). `kafkaStreamer.start()` is not synchronous, it just spins out threads to consume from Kafka and exits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I comment the content of the "finally" block I get error I posted above (in edit)

Comment: This is because you're closing `IgniteDataStreamer` as well. Get rid of try-with-resources block and it will work.

Comment: Hi, I didn't get the application to run yet (because I'm not sure how to read from the cache) but at least I don't get the errors anymore. So I'll mark this question as answered and open a new one for the rest. Thanks again and maybe you can also have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562766/how-to-properly-read-from-ignite-cache